# R stringr unexpected behavior with str_replace & str_pad. Bug or Layer-8 problem?

Tags: r, replace, padding, stringr

I am using R 4.1.3 and the stringr-package 1.4.0 and get some unexpected results from this code:

```
stringr::str_replace(string = "5", 
                     pattern = "([0-9]+)", 
                     replacement = stringr::str_pad(string = "\\1", width = 3,  side = "left",  pad = "0"))
```

**Expected**: "005"; **Result**: "05".

All the parts generate the expected results:

(1) The padding

```
stringr::str_pad(string = "5", width = 3, side = "left", pad = "0")
```

Returns "005"

(2) The regex match

```
stringr::str_replace(string = "5", pattern = "([0-9]+)", replacement = "\\1")
```

Returns "5".

Only the combination of these two leads to unexpected behavior.

For clarification, I already have working code and several solutions to choose from to achive what I want to do, i.e. using an anonymous function:

```
stringr::str_replace(string = "5", 
                     pattern = "([0-9]+)", 
                     replacement = {\(x) stringr::str_pad(string = x, width = 3,  side = "left",  pad = "0")})
```

The intention of the post is to clarifiy why the code at the top does not work.

Thanks in advance for any helpful input.

**Edit**:
It seems that "\1" refers to the content of the capture group, but the character length is determined from the literal "\1".

```
stringr::str_replace(string = "5", 
                     pattern = "([0-9]+)", 
                     replacement = {\(x) as.character(nchar(x))})

stringr::str_replace(string = "5", 
                     pattern = "([0-9]+)", 
                     replacement = as.character(nchar("\\1")))
```

Returns "1" and "2". The second example always returns "2" as replacement for the captured group, independend of its content.

Comment: I could not find it in the documentation but I think when you have a function in `replacement` you need to use an anonymous function, that is part of the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `\1` in the scope of the inner call to `str_pad()` does not mean the first capture group, but rather the number 1 escaped by backslash.  Instead, consider this version as a workaround:

```r
x <- c("5", "12", "345", "1234")
output <- sub("^0{1,3}(\\d{3,})", "\\1", paste0("000", x))
output

[1] "005"  "012"  "345"  "1234"
```

Comment: I don't think that is true because if that is the case then output from OP would be same as `stringr::str_pad(string = "\\1", width = 3, side = "left", pad = "0")`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I have come up with a one-liner way to left pad using `sub()`.

Comment: I agree with Ronak Shah here. If it were `\1` and not the capture group, than the result would be the same as: `stringr::str_pad(string = "\\1", width = 3, side = "left", pad = "0")`

Although the character length of the capture group seems to be determined from `\1`.

`stringr::str_replace(string = "5", pattern = "([0-9]+)", replacement = {\(x) as.character(nchar(x))})` -> "1".

`stringr::str_replace(string = "5", pattern = "([0-9]+)", replacement = as.character(nchar("\\1")))` -> "2".